# Funcion que se aplica al ultimo elemento de carrito

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy haciendo un e-commerse con js para practicar, tengo un JSON con todos los elementos y sus ids.
Dibujo los elementos y el carrito sin ningún problema, pero el problema aparece cuando itero sobre el carrito para agregar las funcionalidades de incrementar y decrementar los elementos desde el mismo carrito. Estas 2 funcionalidades solo se aplican al ultimo elemento.
Ya probe haciendo un forEach dentro de un querySelectorAll y nada :/

```js
let stock;
let carrito = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('carrito')) || [];

function dibujarProductos(products) {
    const section = document.querySelector("#productos")

    section.innerHTML = ""
    products.forEach(prod => {
        section.innerHTML += `
        <div class="card">
        <img src="${prod.imagen}" class="img" alt="${prod.nombre}">
        <div class="info">
            <h3 class="nombre">${prod.nombre}</h3>
            <span class="precio">$${prod.precio}</span>
            <button id="${prod.id}" class="btn">Comprar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
        `
        const agregar = document.getElementById(prod.id)
        agregar.addEventListener('click', () =>{
                agregarCarrito(prod.id)
            })
    });
    }

function agregarCarrito(id) {
    if (!carrito.some(el => el.id === id)) {
        let itemNuevo = stock.find(prod => prod.id === id)
        carrito.push({...itemNuevo, cantidad: 1})
    }else{
        let itemRepetido = carrito.find(prod => prod.id === id)
        itemRepetido.cantidad++;
    }
    dibujarCarrito()
    localStorage.setItem('carrito',JSON.stringify(carrito))
}

function dibujarCarrito() {
    const prodCarrito = document.querySelector("#prod-carrito")
    prodCarrito.innerHTML = ""
    carrito.forEach(el => {
        prodCarrito.innerHTML += `
        <div class="card">
        <img src="${el.imagen}" class="img" alt="${el.nombre}">
        <div class="info">
            <h3 class="nombre">${el.nombre}</h3>
            <span class="precio">Precio unitario:$${el.precio}</span>
            <span>${el.cantidad}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="divBtnCarrito">
        <btn class=" btnCarrito sumar" id="sumar-${el.id}">+</btn>
        <btn class=" btnCarrito restar" id="restar-${el.id}">-</btn>
        <btn class=" btnCarrito eliminar" id="eliminar-${el.id}">Eliminar</btn>
        </div>
    </div>
        `
        const incrementar = document.getElementById(`sumar-${el.id}`)
        incrementar.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
            incrementarProductos(el.id)
        })
        const decrementar = document.getElementById(`restar-${el.id}`)
        decrementar.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
            decrementarProductos(el.id)
        })
    })
}

function incrementarProductos(prod) {
    const producto = carrito.find(el => el.id === prod)
    producto.cantidad++
    dibujarCarrito()
    localStorage.setItem('carrito', JSON.stringify(carrito));
}

function decrementarProductos(prod) {
    const producto = carrito.find(el => el.id === prod)
    if (producto.cantidad > 1) {
        producto.cantidad--
    } else{
        carrito = carrito.filter(el => el.id !== prod)
    }
        dibujarCarrito()
    localStorage.setItem('carrito', JSON.stringify(carrito))
}

fetch("./productos.json")
.then(data => data.json())
.then(data =>{
    stock = data
    dibujarProductos(data)
    dibujarCarrito()
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: .5em;
}


ul {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1em;
    font-size: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: .5px black solid;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}


h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

#productos {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}


.card {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
}

.img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 258px;
    box-shadow: -1px 6px 5px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 6px 5px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 6px 5px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
}

.info {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.nombre {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.precio {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #888;
}

.btn {
    display: block;
    /* Cambiado a bloque para que esté en su propia línea */
    width: 100%;
    /* Opcional: para ocupar el ancho completo disponible */
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #3498db;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #2980b9;
}

#prod-carrito {
    margin-top: .5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1em;
}

.btnCarrito {
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #3498db;
    color: #3498db;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: background-color .15s;
}

.btnCarrito:hover{
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.divBtnCarrito{
    margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
  <header>
      <h1>TIENDA GAMER</h1>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#" class="links">Productos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="links">Contacto</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="links">Precio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="links">Ubicacion</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
      <h2>PRODUCTOS</h2>
      <hr>
      <div id="productos">
      </div>
      <hr>
      <section>
          <h2>Carrito</h2>
          <div id="prod-carrito">

          </div>
      </section>
  </main>
```

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de `productos.json` para poder probar el tema

Comment: creo que eso no se hace de esa forma XD

Answer (score 0):

Los `string` en javascript son inmutables, esto quiere decir que no lo puedes modificar. Lo que modificas es la variable que contiene ese string.

Digamos que tienes esto

```
let UnString = "UnValor";
UnString = UnString + "Otrovalor";

//que es lo mismo que:
//UnString += "Otrovalor";
```

En ningún caso estas modificando el `string`, lo que **modificas** es el valor de ese string por uno **totalmente nuevo**

Entonces tu tienes (en forma resumida) esto:

```
for(){
  prodCarrito.innerHTML += "<div>...</div>";
  incrementar.addEventListener(...);
}
```

En cada iteración estas seteando `section.innerHTML` con un **nuevo valor**, luego el agregas el evento, pero en la próxima iteración vuelves pisas a `section.innerHTML`, esto reemplaza todo su contenido con algo **totalmente nuevo** (aunque estes repitiendo el texto), entonces el evento que habías cargado se pierde, porque apunta a algo que no existe. Y es por esto que te funciona el último, porque al último no lo pisa nadie.

Tienes al menos 3 soluciones:

1.- No usar `template string` y crear los elementos de esta forma

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.classList.add("card");
//etc
let botonIncrementar = document.createElement("button");
//etc
botonIncrementar.addEventListener(//etc)
prodCarrito.appendChild(div);
```

A mi esta opción me desagrada, demasiado trabajo

2.- Colocar otro foreach a continuación

```
carrito.forEach(el => { 
//etc
});

carrito.forEach(el => { 
 const incrementar = document.getElementById(`sumar-${el.id}`)
 incrementar.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
    incrementarProductos(el.id)
 })
 const decrementar = document.getElementById(`restar-${el.id}`)
 decrementar.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
   decrementarProductos(el.id)
 })
});
```

3.- Usar `onclick`

Esta es la solución que me gusta y francamente no se porque hay desarrolladores que se complican tanto. Es parte del estándar y para los casos como el tuyo donde creas elementos a partir de `template string` funciona de maravilla

```
const prodCarrito = document.querySelector("#prod-carrito")
prodCarrito.innerHTML = ""
carrito.forEach(el => {
    prodCarrito.innerHTML += `
    <div class="card">
    <img src="${el.imagen}" class="img" alt="${el.nombre}">
    <div class="info">
        <h3 class="nombre">${el.nombre}</h3>
        <span class="precio">Precio unitario:$${el.precio}</span>
        <span>${el.cantidad}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="divBtnCarrito">
    <btn class=" btnCarrito sumar" onclick="incrementarProductos(${el.id})">+</btn>
    <btn class=" btnCarrito restar" onclick="decrementarProductos(${el.id})">-</btn>
    <btn class=" btnCarrito eliminar" onclick="eliminar(${el.id})">Eliminar</btn>
    </div>
</div>`;
```

---

Como concejo acostumbra a colocar los punto y coma finales